# Редактирование файлов "налету" в phing

Tags: php, build-automation

Приветствую!
Только начал изучать и применять `phing`.
Для примера автоматизирую развертывание проекта `yii2-app-advanced` на локалхосте. Удалось автоматизировать создание локального домена, проекта, определение зависимостей, создание окружения, базы данных.
Далее в планах - миграция пользователей и `RBAC`, но перед этим нужно добавить конфигурирование - как минимум, базы данных. И, скорее всего, будет еще несколько поводов влезть в скрипты проекта автоматом.
Есть ли спец. таски для таких целей, и вообще, каковы практические рекомендации в подобных задачах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, актуально ли это для вас, но:
База данных настраивается вот таким таском:

```
<target name="database" description="Configure database">
    <echo>Configure database connect</echo>
    <input propertyname="hostname" defaultValue="127.0.0.1"
           promptChar="?">Enter hostname of db:</input>
    <input propertyname="database" defaultValue=""
           promptChar="?">Enter name of db:</input>
    <input propertyname="username" defaultValue=""
           promptChar="?">Enter username to access db:</input>
    <input propertyname="password" defaultValue=""
           promptChar="?">Enter password to access db:</input>
    <input propertyname="prefix" defaultValue=""
           promptChar="?">Enter table prefix:</input>
    <copy file="config/db.php.dist"
          tofile="config/db.php" overwrite="true">
        <filterchain>
            <replacetokens begintoken="[[" endtoken="]]">
                <token key="hostname" value="${hostname}" />
                <token key="database" value="${database}" />
                <token key="username" value="${username}" />
                <token key="password" value="${password}" />
                <token key="prefix" value="${prefix}" />
            </replacetokens>
        </filterchain>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Файл шаблона конфигурации базы данных выглядит так:

```
<?php
    return [
        'class'         => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn'           => 'mysql:host=[[hostname]];dbname=[[database]]',
        'username'      => '[[username]]',
        'password'      => '[[password]]',
        'charset'       => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix'   => '[[prefix]]'
   ];
```